# Linq GroupBy Query Timeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

My query with group by always gives timeout error. How can i make it work properly?

```
  var result = products.Join(_Context.Barcode, firstTable => firstTable.ProductId, barcode => barcode.B_ProductId, (resultTable, resultProduct) => new
                {
                    product = resultTable,
                    barcode = resultProduct
                }).Join(_Context.Stock, secondTable => secondTable.barcode.Barcode, stock => stock.Barcode, (finalResult, finalStock) => new
                {
                    Product = finalResult.product,
                    Stock = finalStock,
                    Barcode = finalResult.barcode
                }).GroupBy(x => x.Product.ProductId).Select(I => new ProductDTO()
                {
                    InStock = I.Sum(x => x.Stock.StockCount) > 0 ? true : false,
                    Url = I.Select(x => x.Product.Url).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Name= I.Select(x => x.Product.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                    ImagePath = I.Select(x => x.Product.ImagePath).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Tax = I.Select(x => x.Product.Tax).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Price = I.Select(x => x.Product.Price).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Id = I.Select(x => x.Product.ProductId).FirstOrDefault(),
    
                });

 return result.ToList();
```

Thank you.

Comment: try to find out what sql query is generated by LINQ and optimize it

Comment: Actually this query is not translatable to the SQL. I assume you have used EF Core 2.x which silently loads whole table into the memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
 _Context.Database.CommandTimeout = 600;
```

use time out function before the result.